# The cohomology groups corresponding to a modified global sections functor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology, derived-functors

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf on the big etale site of $Sm_k$. I am looking for a way to calculate a modified version of sheaf cohomology. Let $X$ be a smooth scheme and $Z$ a closed sub-scheme. After taking an injective resolution of $\mathcal{F}|_X$, instead of taking global sections, let's take the modified global sections $\Gamma'_Z$, which is those global sections $s$ such that the image of $s$ under the pullback  in the global sections of $Z$ is zero (pullback of big sites not the small site on $X$ i.e. each sheaf on $Sm_k$ defines a presheaf which is a contravariant functor from $Sm_k$ to groups and this is the presheaf pullback). Is there a way to understand the resulted cohomology groups?

More precisely the case I am interested in is the following: Replace $\mathcal{F}$ with a complex of sheaves corresponding to $R\varprojlim\limits_{r}\mu_{l^r}^{\otimes n}$ which calculates the continuous etale cohomology of the inverse system of sheaves defined by $\mu_{l^r}^{\otimes n}$ as $r$ varies. The scheme $X$ is an open subschemes of the algebraic simplex $\Delta^m$ that does not contain the vertices. The subscheme $Z$ is the faces of the simplex (their intersection with the open subscheme). Writing an injective resolution for $R\varprojlim\limits_{r}\mu_{l^r}^{\otimes n}$ on $Sm_k$ then restricting to $X$ and calculating the cohomologies of the left exact functor $\Gamma'_Z$, how do they compare to the continuous etale cohomology of $X$?

For example it is known that the cohomologies of $R\varprojlim\limits_{r}\mu_{l^r}^{\otimes n}$ are torsion for $i\geq 2n+2$ if the base field $k$ is $\mathbb{F}_p$. Does the same hold for the cohomologies of $\Gamma'_Z$ in the specific example above?